# How to disable light-locker in Xubuntu 14.04 via command line?

Tags: 14.04, light-locker

I have searched thru the forums but I haven't found the answer yet. I have come across an issue in which light locker automatically locks the screen, therefore I want to bundle the startup of my app with a cli command that also disables light-locker. Anyone has an idea?

[image: screenshot of Light Locker Settings window showing the switch for Enable light-locker set to off, with text added to the image asking if there is a cli commad to disable light-locker and pointing to that switch]

Comment: @eliahkagan Thanks for putting the image inline!

Comment: [That](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1169604/revisions) was actually @user3140225 -- I just added some [alt text](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alt_attribute) while approving [the edit](https://askubuntu.com/review/suggested-edits/974242).

Comment: @user3140225 Thanks for editing the image to be shown inline!

Comment: `light-locker` is a running process and would have to be terminated, `killall -u $USER -s TERM light-locker` might work.

Comment: Open `/usr/share/light-locker-settings/light-locker-settings/light-locker-settings.py` with a text editor and read a bit, python is pretty good understandable and you can see how the GUI does it.

Comment: @ChengFei No problem! I also earned some points myself for editing your post, so it's beneficial for me too! Regarding your problem, I have completely uninstalled light locker, because it was buggy for me. I now use `xscreensaver`. Despite being a bit ugly, I never had any problem with it. If you want to try it, you can install it with `sudo apt install xscreensaver`.

Comment: @user3140225 you are probably right. Maybe uninstalling light-locker might be the best solution here.

Comment: @ChengFei I added my comment as an answer, along with some steps to run `xscreensaver` at startup.

Comment: I think Xubuntu 14.04 is not supported anymore.

Comment: You can disable the locker in Sartup and Sessions dialog.

Comment: @user3140225 thanks a lot! I accepted your answer as this provided the best solution for me :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can completely uninstall `light-locker`, and use `xscreensaver`. Despite being a bit ugly, it works well and I had never had any problems with it.

To uninstall `light-locker`, run:

```
sudo apt purge light-locker
```

Then install `xscreensaver` by running:

```
sudo apt install xscreensaver
```

After that, run `xscreensaver` from your menu and click *OK* if it asks you to enable the `xscreensaver` daemon.

To have `xscreensaver` start with your computer:

- Run *Session and Startup* from your menu.
- Select the *Application Autostart* tab.
- Click *Add*.
- On the pop-up window write the following:

[image: xscreensaver autostart popup]

Restart your computer. `xscreensaver` should be up and running.